# shorting the 9/12V AC at transformer?

Tags: transformer, ac, power-electronics

[image: IR based lamp actuator]

- 1st sense IR - no relay ON
- 2nd sense IR - 9 VAC relay ON
- 3rd sense IR - 12 VAC relay ON

Mean while if operate the switch there is a chance shorting the 9V/12 VAC at transformer?
Relay datasheet:https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/657851/TIANBOGANGLIANELECTRONICS/HJR-3FF-S-Z/1

Comment: Datasheet link for the relays, please. Add it into the question - not in the comments.

Comment: You've added a link to your Google drive which is not open access. Please change it to a link to the manufacturer's website.

Comment: The edited link still points to your Google drive.

Comment: The third edit link is for a HJR-3FF relay. Your post says it's an SC5-S. They're two different part numbers. All we need to know is does the relay have changeover contacts or just an NO (normally open) contact?

Comment: The linked datasheet has a -Z (Form C) and -H (Form A) type. We don't know which you are using. You are making this very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You have not used proper switch symbols in your drawing but I guess you mean that you are considering wiring them as shown in Figure 1a. This will be a problem as there is a danger of short-circuiting the 9 VAC to the 12 VAC transformer tap.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh8je4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The SC5-S-DC5V relay appears to have a change-over contact so you can wire them as shown in Figure 1b. This prevents short-circuit of the transformer.